# Python : efficiency concerns in parallel async calls to fetch data from web services

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrent.futures

I am writing a python script to fetch a list of hosts corresponding to a particular group_id. I will be using a web service call to fetch the same. The number of hosts can be in 10,000. Now for each host I will fetch a value called property from another web service.

so   group-id ----(ws1)-----10000s of hosts --(ws2)----property for each

I am using concurrent.futures as shown in the following code. But it does not seems to be a clean design and unlikely to scale well.

```
def call_ws_1(group_id):
     #fetch list of hosts for group_id


def call_ws_2(host):
     #find property for host


def fetch_hosts(group_ids):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        future_to_grp_id = {executor.submit(call_ws_1, group_id): group_id for group_id in group_ids}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_grp_id):
            group_id = future_to_grp_id[future]
            try:
                hosts = future.result()#this is a list
            except Exception as exp:
                #logging etc
            else:
                 fetch_property(hosts)


def fetch_property(hosts):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        future_to_host = {executor.submit(call_ws_2, host): host for host in hosts}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_host):
            host = future_to_host[future]
            try:
                host_prop = future.result()#String
            except Exception as exp:
                #logging etc
            else:
                 #Save host and property to DB
```

1. Will there be any advantage using ProcessPoolExecuter ?
2. How about fetching all the hosts first (around 40000 of them) and then calling ws to fetch property
3. Any other suggestion to improve this design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `ProcessPoolExecutor` has the advantage of not being affected by the GIL. With `ThreadPoolExecutor`, the GIL will prevent more than one thread from running at a time, unless you're doing I/O. The good news is it looks like both of your threads will primarily be doing I/O, but any kind of processing that occurs in each thread before or after making their web services calls will not truly happen concurrently, which will hurt your performance. `ProcessPoolExecutor` will not have this restriction, but it has the added overhead of sending the `group_id` and `host` data between processes. If you've got tens of thousands of hosts, sending those one at a time between processes is going to have fairly significant overhead.
2. I don't think this change alone will change performance too much, since in the end you're still sending each host, one at a time, to a thread for processing.

As for number 3, if your worker threads are really doing almost nothing but I/O, this approach may work fine. But with threads, any CPU-bound work going in the workers is going to murder your performance. I took your exact program layout and implemented your two workers like this:

```
def call_ws_1(group_id):
    return list(range(20))

def call_ws_2(host):
    sum(range(33000000))  # CPU-bound
    #time.sleep(1)  # I/O-bound
    return "{} property".format(host)
```

And executed everything like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    fetch_hosts(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
    end = time.time()
    print("Total time: {}".format(end-start))
```

Using `time.sleep`, the output is:

```
Fetching hosts for d
Fetching hosts for a
Fetching hosts for c
Fetching hosts for b
Fetching hosts for e
Total time: 25.051292896270752
```

Using the `sum(range(33000000))` calculation, the performance is much worse:

```
Fetching hosts for d
Fetching hosts for a
Fetching hosts for c
Fetching hosts for b
Fetching hosts for e
Total time: 75.81612730026245
```

Note that the calculation takes about one second on my laptop:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("sum(range(33000000))", number=1)
1.023313045501709
>>> timeit.timeit("sum(range(33000000))", number=1)
1.029937982559204
```

So each worker takes about a second. But because one is CPU-bound, and therefore affected by the GIL, threads perform horribly.

Here's a `ProcessPoolExecutor` using `time.sleep`:

```
Fetching hosts for a
Fetching hosts for b
Fetching hosts for c
Fetching hosts for d
Fetching hosts for e
Total time: 25.169482469558716
```

Now using `sum(range(33000000))`:

```
Fetching hosts for a
Fetching hosts for b
Fetching hosts for c
Fetching hosts for d
Fetching hosts for e
Total time: 43.54587936401367
```

As you can see, while performance is still worse than `time.sleep` (probably because the calculation takes a bit longer than a second, and CPU-bound work has to compete with everything else running on the laptop), it still greatly outperforms the threaded version.

However, I suspect that as the number of hosts goes up, the cost of IPC will slow you down quite a bit. Here's how the `ThreadPoolExecutor` does with 10000 hosts, but a worker process that does nothing (it just returns):

```
Fetching hosts for c
Fetching hosts for b
Fetching hosts for d
Fetching hosts for a
Fetching hosts for e
Total time: 9.535644769668579
```

Compare to `ProcessPoolExecutor`:

```
Fetching hosts for c
Fetching hosts for b
Fetching hosts for a
Fetching hosts for d
Fetching hosts for e
Total time: 36.59257411956787
```

So there's its 4x slower with `ProcessPoolExecutor`, all caused by the cost of IPC.

So, what's all this mean? I think your best possible performance would come by using `ProcessPoolExecutor`, but additionally batching your IPC, so that you send large chunks of hosts into a child process, rather than just sending one host at a time.

Something like this (untested, but gives you the idea):

```
import time
import itertools
import concurrent.futures
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Pool

def call_ws_1(group_id):
    return list(range(10000))

def call_ws_2(hosts):  # This worker now works on a list of hosts
    host_results = []
    for host in hosts:
        host_results.append(( host, "{} property".format(host)))  # returns a list of (host, property) tuples
    return host_results

def chunk_list(l):
    chunksize = len(l) // 16  # Break the list into smaller pieces
    it = [iter(l)] * chunksize
    for item in itertools.zip_longest(*it):
        yield tuple(filter(None, item))

def fetch_property(hosts):
    with Pool(max_workers=4) as executor:
        futs = []
        for chunk in chunk_list(hosts):
            futs.append(concurrent.futures.submit(call_ws_2, chunk))
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futs):
            try:
                 results = future.result()
            except Exception as exp:
                print("Got %s" % exp)
            else:
                for result in results:
                    host, property = result
                    # Save host and property to DB

def fetch_hosts(group_ids):
    with Pool(max_workers=4) as executor:
        future_to_grp_id = {executor.submit(call_ws_1, group_id): group_id for group_id in group_ids}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_grp_id):
            group_id = future_to_grp_id[future]
            try:
                hosts = future.result()#this is a list
            except Exception as exp:
                print("Got %s" % exp)
            else:
                print("Fetching hosts for {}".format(group_id))
                fetch_property(hosts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    fetch_hosts(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
    end = time.time()
    print("Total time: {}".format(end-start))
```

Comment: The solution you proposed was a very useful guideline. I am still doing some experimenting and tweaking some knobs, but thanks for a very good head start.

Comment: I have another basic question about futures. Please refer to your code for method `fetch_hosts()` in the `else` part you are calling `fetch_property(hosts)`. How is this called ? Is it a blocking call or it is asynchronous too. When `hosts` are fetched they will be passed to this method and then even if the next future returns with new set of hosts it will be blocked unless the previous call to `fetch_property` returns.OR multiple async calls are made to `fetch_property` as and when hosts are available.